# Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject in FreeRadius tutorial

Tags: docker, freeradius

I want to mount a FreeRADIUS server for create an Enterprise WiFi and I have problems with the [official tutorial](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/Basic-configuration-HOWTO). I tried [WPA 2 Enterprise from scratch using a Raspberry Pi](https://me.m01.eu/blog/2012/05/wpa-2-enterprise-from-scratch-on-a-raspberry-pi/) and [FreeRadius Server installation and configuration on Linux system](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/freeradius-server-installation-and-configuration-on-linux-system-855741/) without success.
I have trouble when I try to perform the test `radtest -x testing password localhost 0 testing123`. The server response is:

```
Sent Access-Request Id 86 from 0.0.0.0:35959 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 77
    User-Name = "testing"
    User-Password = "password"
    NAS-IP-Address = 172.18.0.2
    NAS-Port = 0
    Message-Authenticator = 0x00
    Cleartext-Password = "password"
Received Access-Reject Id 86 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:35959 length 20
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

I'm mounting the server inside a Docker Container, which Dockerfile is:

```
FROM base/archlinux

RUN pacman -Syyu; pacman -S freeradius make inetutils --noconfirm

EXPOSE 1812
EXPOSE 1813

# Archlinux is not installig freeradius on /etc/raddb but when I launch
# the server, the main proccess looks at that directorie
RUN cp -r /etc/raddb.default /etc/raddb

RUN sed -i '1 i\testing Cleartext-Password := password' /etc/raddb/users

ENTRYPOINT [ "radiusd", "-X" ]
```

To run the docker container:

`docker build -t freeradius .`

`docker run freeradius`

And launch the test:

`docker exec container_id radtest -x testing password localhost 0 testing123`

Could anyone help me please?
Regards

Comment: I believe the default user is bob

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell I tested 'bob' as username without success. Can you explain it with more details, please? I followed the freeradius official tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I achive that using a freeradius docker image based on Ubuntu (https://github.com/tpdock/freeradius) instead of ArchLinux. And using MySQL for user authentification instead of users file (`/etc/raddb/users`)

There's the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7 
    volumes:
      - ./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./db/volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: freeradius
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: freeradius
      MYSQL_DATABASE: freeradius
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  freeradius-server-docker:
    restart: always
    image: tpdock/freeradius
    ports:
      - 1812:1812/udp
      - 1813:1813/udp
    environment:
      RADIUS_LISTEN_IP: '*'
      RADIUS_CLIENTS: secret@127.0.0.1
      RADIUS_SQL: 'true'
      RADIUS_DB_HOST: db
      RADIUS_DB_NAME: freeradius
      RADIUS_DB_USERNAME: freeradius
      RADIUS_DB_PASSWORD: freeradius
    links:
      - db
```

And the MySQL script on `./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql` to insert an user:

```
insert into radcheck (username, attribute, op, value) values ('test', 'Cleartext-Password', ':=', 'test');
```

I also had to insert the schema in `./db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql`

Schema getted from: [schema.sql](https://github.com/tpdock/freeradius/blob/master/templates/schema.sql)

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on how the FreeRADIUS users file works (`/etc/raddb/users`).  As that's what your tutorial appears to be using to store test credentials.  The users file is also how most people get started with FreeRADIUS as it encapsulates a lot of functionality in a relatively simple format.

I wrote quite a detailed answer to another question about the users file format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658080/freeradius-users-operators).  I would read through that to get an overview of how the users file works and create your own entry.

At a minimum an entry to authenticate a user will contain their username and a reference credential of some kind.

```
bob Cleartext-Password == 'password'
```

Would allow the user 'bob' to authenticate with the password 'password'.

Note: You will need to restart or `kill -HUP` the RADIUS daemon to get it to re-read changes to the users file.

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern!!!

Users "shold be" listed in /usr/local/etc/raddb/users, NOT the one one in /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-conf/authorized as indicated by some tutorial.

Comment: I checked this. Looks like mine automatically has a symlink: `/etc/raddb/users -> ./mods-config/files/authorize`