# FreeRadius can't set custom variable

Tags: freeradius, strongswan

We want to setup StrongSwan VPN with FreeRadius for authentication. In addition to that we want to assign different subnets to users based on AD-Groups. StrongSwan uses the class attribute in a access-accept reply for that (https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EapRadius).

To my knowledge it is possible to use custom attributes in FreeRadius to store data used during the reply/proxy/control… process and send that back to StrongSwan.

Unfortunately this is not working in our FreeRadius environment and the custom attribute stays empty. It is however possible to access attributes already existing in the reply list.

This configuration for example sends back an empty Variable Reply-Message.

/etc/raddb/dictionary:

```
ATTRIBUTE       test                    3000    string
```

/etc/raddb/users

```
DEFAULT test = “TESTTEST”
```

/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default

```
…
post-auth {
…
update reply {
                Reply-Message := "%{control:test}"
}  
…
}
```

Log-Output:

```
(11)     [exec] = noop
(11)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(11)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(11)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(11)       else {
(11)         [noop] = noop
(11)       } # else = noop
(11)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(11)     update reply {
(11)       EXPAND %{control:test}
(11)          -->
(11)       Reply-Message :=
(11)     } # update reply = noop
(11)   } # post-auth = noop
(11) Sent Access-Accept Id 5 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:50913 length 0
(11)   MS-MPPE-Recv-Key = 0xd23e4723df9ff904741b91827518aaa48dcbca27204024965d37fdb6bece0270
(11)   MS-MPPE-Send-Key = 0x4e7de0fc944a5114ab435df43fa943901870741a86571e3ccddef11b82e406e1
(11)   EAP-Message = 0x03050004
(11)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
(11)   User-Name = "raduser"
(11)   Reply-Message  := ""
(11) Finished request
```

FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.19

According to this guides, the configuration above should work:

- [returning custom user attributes in the radius reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918015/returning-custom-user-attributes-in-the-radius-reply)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/939980/freeradius-return-user-groups-in-class-field

Is there anything we’re missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should work.  You'll need to post the debug output from running `radiusd -X`

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell
Can I send you the output via email (e.g. the one on your GitHub page) or private message somehow?

Comment: Yeah send it to my FreeRADIUS one

Answer (score 1):

Your reply message should be formatted as

```
 Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

In your configuration file, you defined `DEFAULT test = “TESTTEST”` but in reply message you have mentioned `"%{control:test}"`.

please try with it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. My problem is that I cannot use custom variables.